# URLs with trailing slash say site in maintainence mode, others don't, site isn't in maintenance mode

Tags: 7, uri, maintenance-mode

Something very strange has happened and I'm at a complete loss as to how to go about working out the cause.

I used Backup / Migrate module to restore a backup of my live site's database (let's call it *somesite.com*) onto my dev site's database (let's call it *dev.somesite.com*) after copying the files over.

I visited *dev.somesite.com/admin/* and was surprised to be told it was in maintenance mode. I did the usual maintenance mode fixes: `drush vset maintenance_mode 0`, checking that the contents of *variable > maintenance_mode* in the database was `i:0;`, but it still showed as maintenance mode.

A little trial and error later, I discovered that *dev.somesite.com/admin* did work, and it seemed **having a trailing slash in the URL would show the maintenance mode page**.

What could possibly be causing such a strange behaviour? My first thought was, since it's a URL formatting issue, there might be a mistake in my `.htaccess` file, but it looks fine and hasn't changed.

---

**Update**: a little more testing seems to show that this only happens for URLs the user doesn't have access to. For example, *dev.somesite.com/admin/* while logged in gives the expected user access error, *dev.somesite.com/about-us/* while not logged in redirects to *dev.somesite.com/about-us* and then works fine, but *dev.somesite.com/admin/* while not logged in gives the maintenance page not the access denied page.

So, it's not as serious a problem as I first thought, but it's still strange and smells like a sign I might have misconfigured something which might in turn have more serious consequences elsewhere - but I don't know what this could be. I've looked at my Global Redirect settings and they look fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you already cleared the cache? Maybe it's just that
2. Try putting this code `$conf['site_offline'] = 0;` into settings.php to see what happens :)